# Microsoft Word: want to delete text between same two words on multiple pages

Tags: microsoft-word

Am hoping someone can help... I have a large number of profiles / records contained in a single word doc that I need to edit down, and was hoping to find a way to do a large part of the work automatically.

Each new record starts on a new page with a persons name (e.g. "Peter Scott") and continues with free text up until the word "Experience". Lets call this 'Section 1'.

It then continues in free text from the word "Experience" in free text to the word "Education". Lets call this Section 2.

Finally it goes from the word "Education" to a manual line break (^m). This is Section 3.

Is there a way I can removed Sections 1 & 3 easily across all records / pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MS Word provides capability to search and replace text using regular expressions, also called regex.  Working with regex's is not trivial, so you will need to put in some work to learn and use them - but there are plenty of articles out there.  [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Search with Wildcards, `Education*Experience`. Do a controlled replace (i.e. don't replace all). You'll have to manually remove the first Section 1 and the last Section 3